# Using Snowflake SQL to Create Moving Anchor Dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset of services that should only be performed every 30 days, but I found the services were being performed more frequently than that. I need to create a Snowflake SQL query that will identify these services. Specifically, the first date-of-service should be flagged as an “anchor_row”.  If the second date-of-service is within 30 days of the previous “anchor_row”, then the row should be flagged.  The same for the 3rd date-of-service, 4th, 5th, etc.  However, if the 2nd date-of-service (or 3rd, 4th…) is 30 or more days after the “anchor_row”, then that row should be identified as the “anchor_row” and the process should start over again for the remaining rows.

An example of what I am looking for is below. I would prefer to use window functions instead of joins to make the code more readable if possible, but that is not a requirement if there is a simpler solution.

Here is an excel screen shot of an example of what I have

[Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YcMR.png)

| Contractor_ID | Date_of_Service |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 |
| A | 1/21/2021 |
| A | 1/23/2021 |
| A | 2/12/2021 |
| A | 5/1/2021 |
| A | 5/21/2021 |
| A | 7/1/2021 |
| B | 3/1/2021 |
| B | 3/31/2021 |
| B | 4/20/2021 |
| B | 5/10/2021 |
| B | 5/30/2021 |
| B | 11/15/2021 |
| B | 12/5/2021 |
| B | 12/25/2021 |

Here is a screen print of what I want

[Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W0Vi.png)

| Contractor_ID | Date_of_Service | Anchor_Row | Last_Anchor_Date | Flagged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 0 |
| A | 1/21/2021 | 0 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| A | 1/23/2021 | 0 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| A | 2/12/2021 | 1 | 2/12/2021 | 0 |
| A | 5/1/2021 | 1 | 5/1/2021 | 0 |
| A | 5/21/2021 | 0 | 5/1/2021 | 1 |
| A | 7/1/2021 | 1 | 7/1/2021 | 0 |
| B | 3/1/2021 | 1 | 3/1/2021 | 0 |
| B | 3/31/2021 | 1 | 3/31/2021 | 0 |
| B | 4/20/2021 | 0 | 3/31/2021 | 1 |
| B | 5/10/2021 | 1 | 5/10/2021 | 0 |
| B | 5/30/2021 | 0 | 5/10/2021 | 1 |
| B | 11/15/2021 | 1 | 11/15/2021 | 0 |
| B | 12/5/2021 | 0 | 11/15/2021 | 1 |
| B | 12/25/2021 | 1 | 12/25/2021 | 0 |

Here is an example of what I tried that doesn't work.

I started by creating a new column called "last_anchor_date" that was 100% Null.  I then tried a case statement that would update the last_anchor_date using a lag function if the date_of_service was greater than the last_anchor_date.  However, when I did this, it created a second "last_anchor_date" column.

```
'''
create or replace table test (contractor_id varchar, date_of_service date);


insert into test 
values
('A',to_date('1/1/2021'))
,('A',to_date('1/21/2021'))
,('A',to_date('1/23/2021'))
,('A',to_date('2/12/2021'))
,('A',to_date('5/1/2021'))
,('A',to_date('5/21/2021'))
,('A',to_date('7/1/2021'))
,('B',to_date('3/1/2021'))
,('B',to_date('3/31/2021'))
,('B',to_date('4/20/2021'))
,('B',to_date('5/10/2021'))
,('B',to_date('5/30/2021'))
,('B',to_date('11/15/2021'))
,('B',to_date('12/5/2021'))
,('B',to_date('12/25/2021'))
;

alter table test add column last_anchor_date date;

    select * 
        ,row_number() over (partition by contractor_id order by date_of_service) as row_num 
        ,case when row_num = 1 then date_of_service 
              when row_num > 1 and date_of_service - lag(last_anchor_date) over (partition by contractor_id order by date_of_service) >= 30 
                    then date_of_service 
              when row_num > 1 and date_of_service - lag(last_anchor_date) over (partition by contractor_id order by date_of_service) < 30 
                    then lag(last_anchor_date) over (partition by contractor_id order by date_of_service) 
         end as last_anchor_date
            
    from test
    order by contractor_id, date_of_service;
'''
```

Comment: Change your pictures of "have" and "want" to text. Easiest would be to separate columns by the vertical bar, a title line, and the data. Put three backticks (```) on one line before and after the data